# Vue-Router Flexbox not scrolling properly (or at all)

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a component with a router-view inside it that can display a flexbox. I've tried several different solutions to flex-boxes not scrolling properly and they all either result in no scrolling, or scrolling, but it doesn't quite reach the bottom (the last element in the v-for ends up getting cut off.)

Here is the template and relevant styles for the router view

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" ref="modal">
        <div class="modalcontent" ref="content">
            <p class="goback" @click="closeAnimation" ref="goback">←</p>
            <div class="title">
                <h1>Questions & Answers</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="routerview">
                <router-view :posts="posts" v-slot="{ Component }">
                    <transition name="slide-in" mode="out-in">
                        <component :is="Component" />
                    </transition>
                </router-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>



<style>

.routerview {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    outline: 10px red;
}

</style>
```

and for the flexbox:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flex-container" ref="flexcontainer">
                <div class="question" v-for="post in posts" :key="post._id" @click="this.$router.push(`/forum/question/${post._id}`)">
                    <h1 class="qTitle">{{ post.title }}</h1>
                    <p class="qReplyAmt">{{ post.replies.length }} repl<span v-if="!plural(post.replies.length)">y</span><span v-else>ies</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>You've reached the end</p>
    </div>
</template>


<style scoped>
.question {
    width: 98%;
    height: fit-content;
    min-height: 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 2px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.question:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 107, 107);
    color: white;
}

.qTitle {
    display: block;
}

.qReplyAmt {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 15px;
    flex: 1;
}
</style>
```

I've tried:

- setting a height on .container, .routerview, .flex-container
- setting overflow-y to auto & scroll on .container, .routerview, .flex-container
- and a bunch of other answers i've found on how to fix flexboxes not scrolling

Comment: for clarification: To get it to do any scrolling at all, the height on any of .container, .routerview, or .flex-container has to be 100vh. 100% doesn't work. only at 100vh does it allow scrolling, and thats when the weird cutoff at the end is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Here is the updated styles:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 15px;
    flex: 1;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 125px;
}

.container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I added the `.container` styles to make it actually scroll and added `margin-bottom: 125px;` to fix the issue with the last item being cut off.